# Lead and Contact forms blank after upgrade to CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

Since we upgraded a CRM 2013 organization, certain user roles get blank forms (nothing below the command bar) when they try to view a contact or lead record in the system.

The role that they are assigned to has read permissions for both of these record types. Users with the system administrator role have no problem opening the form. There is no error message that pops up or is in the console of the browser developer tools. This is happening in all three major Windows browsers.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the fix was to add the Read privilege on the *Campaign* entity in the role. I don't know if this is related to the *Last Campaign Date* field on the records, but that fixed the issue.

[image: Role Update]